Visual Studio 2022 IntelliSense folder permissions with C++ project located within WSL2 using Windows x64 CMake GUI
When I use   to configure a new C++ project located in a WSL2 directory, opening it in Visual Studio 2022 presents an Ok/Cancel message box (contents below) indicating that a non-default location will be used to store IntelliSense files ("Found a suitable location for browsing database and IntelliSense files"). For at least one subdirectory of build (i.e. build\.vs\hello\v17), I "do not have permissions to write to this directory".
I can choose Ok for the non-default location, but even on a hello world test, an initial build gives 12 MSB8064 Custom build warnings ending with "This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly".
I do have write access from within WSL2, and also from file explorer. Is it possible to configure WSL2 to avoid such situations?
Visual C++ found a suitable location to store its browsing database and IntelliSense files for the solution "\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-24.04\home\XXXXX\myrepo\1_hello\build\.vs\hello\v17\Browse.VC.db."

Visual C++ examined the folder "\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-24.04\home\XXXXX\myrepo\1_hello\build\.vs\hello\v17." This folder is not suitable because of the following:
You do not have permissions to write to this directory.

Because a 'Fallback Location' was not specified in the C++ Advanced Options, Visual C++ is attempting to use your temporary directory.

Visual C++ examined the folder "C:\Users\YYYYYYY\AppData\Local\Temp\VC++\BROWSE.VC-ab8884e7." This folder is suitable because of the following:
The directory is on a local drive.

The 'Fallback Location' is configurable under C++ Advanced Options.

Press OK to use this location.
Press Cancel to disable C++ browsing information and IntelliSense for this session.

